How can I convert this SQL query to linq when I have sub query, grouping and having clause?
I'm really struggling to convert the following SQL to a LINQ query. Can anyone help?
select invoice, date, amount, Name 
from payments 
where invoice in (select invoice
                  from payments
                  where invoicelike 'EVENT%' 
                    and status = 3 
                    and date >= '2023-11-01 00:00'
                  group by invoice
                  having count(*) > 1)
order by invoice, date desc


According to your scenario, you could break this query into two part in linq . In first part bring the invoice by event then filters payments to include only those whose invoice is in the previously filtered invoices in first part.

Yes, this query could be translated into LINQ:
var date = new DateTime(2023, 11, 1);
var forFilter = context.Payments
    .Where(x => x.Invoice.StartsWith("EVENT") && x.Status == 3 && x.Date > date)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Invoice)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Key);

var data = await context.Payments
    .Where(x => forFilter.Contains(x.Invoice))
    .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

Example: I have implemented simple example using my database:
app.MapGet("/get-special", async (ExampleWebApiContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
{
    var forFilter = context.Movies
        .Where(x => x.ReleaseYear > 1000)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .Select(x => x.Key);

    var data = await context.Movies
        .Where(x => forFilter.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

    return data;
});

which produced query as desired:


Try this, the point is we can use the dbContext inside the Where method which turns to sub query:
var date = new DateTime(2023, 11, 1);
var result = await dbContext.Payments
    .Where(p => dbContext.Payments /*Here is the sub query*/
        .Where(sub => sub.Invoice.StartWith("EVENT")
            && sub.Status == 3
            && sub.Date >= date)
        .GroupBy(sub => sub.Invoice)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .Contains(p.Invoice)/*This will be translated to IN query*/)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Invoice)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Date)
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        p.Invoice,
        p.Date,
        p.Amount,
        p.Name
    })
    .ToListAsync();


This will be only one query to the database:)
